# iOS + UIlabel with Start and end Quotes in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to create a UITableViewCell like the one in picture. It has a UILabel and at the start and end Start and endQuotes. I have already looked at NSAttributedText string but it looks horrible when quotes are included in text. Do let me know if anyone has ideas

[image]

Comment: What di you get when you tried with NSAttributedText to have the quote? Any render could be interesting to help us get closer to the wanted render. With NSAttributedText, you could play with color, italic, size, baseline...

Comment: If you check font size of Quotes is much bigger than that of text...And because of the bottom padding of Quotes...the height of the first line becomes way bigger than others messing up the UI...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to make sure the text starts at the specified distance to the right, e.g. by inserting spaces. Then you would have to find out the x position of the last character - this should also be possible. The quotes could be images that you then superimpose.

For finding the x of the last line, you could calculate the total height, figure out how much of the text fits if you remove one line, then calculate the width of the remaining text.

The new `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` should be enough to make these calculations.